# c# How do constructors with parameters work?

Tags: c#

I don't understand how constructors work. I'm trying to bring these figures into the main program from the class, however whenever i try to use the construtor on the main program, it comes up with "Class Fooditem does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments". This is extremely confusing as i have one right there called `public food(string name, int numberserved)`. I don't understand why this message is popping up and i don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FoodItem firstfood = new FoodItem("Spagetti", 3);
            Console.WriteLine("The First Food is '{0}' And it serves {1}",   firstfood.Name, firstfood.NumberServed);
        }
    }

class FoodItem
    {
        string _name;       
        int _numberserved;

        public void food(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
            _numberserved = 0;
        }
        public void food(string name, int numberserved)
        {
            _name = name;
            NumberServed = numberserved;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
        }

        public int NumberServed
        {
            get
            {
                return _numberserved;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value > 4)
                {
                    _numberserved = 4;
                }
                else
                {
                    _numberserved = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your class name?

Comment: constructor's name should be as same as class name, you don't have any constructor in your class.

Comment: Your constructor needs to have the same name as the class.

Comment: You don't have `public food(string name, int numberserved)`.  Had you had that, you would get a syntax error.

Comment: [Have a read of the documentation for C# constructors.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Constructors should have the same name as your class, and no return type:

```
class FoodItem
{
    string _name;       
    int _numberserved;

    public FoodItem(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _numberserved = 0;
    }
    public FoodItem(string name, int numberserved)
    {
        _name = name;
        NumberServed = numberserved;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class is called `FoodItem` then the constructors should also be called `FoodItem` and have no return value:

```
public class FoodItem
{
    public FoodItem()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public FoodItem(string name, int numberserved)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

You can chain constructors together by using the `: this` construct. It can work either way:

```
    public FoodItem()
    {
        // Do basic stuff
    }

    public FoodItem(string name, int numberserved) : this()
    {
        // Do other stuff
    }
```

or

```
    public FoodItem() : this ("defaultName", 0)
    {
    }
```

What you do depends completely on your application.

Answer (score 0):

You named your constructor wrongly. Change it to FoodItem like this:

```
class FoodItem
{
    string _name;       
    int _numberserved;

    public FoodItem(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _numberserved = 0;
    }
    public FoodItem(string name, int numberserved)
    {
        _name = name;
        NumberServed = numberserved;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }

    public int NumberServed
    {
        get
        {
            return _numberserved;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 4)
            {
                _numberserved = 4;
            }
            else
            {
                _numberserved = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have altered your code and it will work now.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FoodItem firstfood = new FoodItem("Spagetti", 3);
            Console.WriteLine("The First Food is '{0}' And it serves {1}",   firstfood.Name, firstfood.NumberServed);
        }
    }

class FoodItem
    {
        string _name;       
        int _numberserved;

        public void food(string name)  
        public FoodItem()
        {
            _name = name;
            _numberserved = 0;
        }
        public void food(string name, int numberserved)
        public FoodItem(string name, int numberserved)

        {
            _name = name;
            NumberServed = numberserved;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
        }

        public int NumberServed
        {
            get
            {
                return _numberserved;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value > 4)
                {
                    _numberserved = 4;
                }
                else
                {
                    _numberserved = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Kindly let me know your thoughts or feedback.

thanks
karthik